# Ignition Switch

Tags: toyota, corolla, ignition-switch

My Radio goes off and on and cars stalls while driving. I am pretty sure this is The ignition switch. Do i buy the ignition lock cylinder or ask for switch whats the difference? 2002 toyota Carolla.

Comment: lock cylinder is for the key, ignition switch is the electrical part turned by the lock cylinder. Get the ign switch.

Comment: Sounds like a worn ignition switch. If you jiggle it and the engine dies, most certainly the ignition switch, or loose wiring to the ignition switch.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!